# How to stop Audio?

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, mp3

Here is my problem, when I start the Activity the Music start like I want it to, but when I leave the Activity (by pressing the back button) the Application crashes and "stopped unexpectedly"  :( All I want to do is have the audio STOP and go to another activity without the unexpected stop. How can I do this?

```
public class Run extends Activity {

/** The OpenGL View */
private GLSurfaceView glSurface;
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

/**
 * Initiate the OpenGL View and set our own
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Create an Instance with this Activity
    glSurface = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    //Set our own Renderer and hand the renderer this Activity Context
    glSurface.setRenderer(new Lesson06(this));
    //Set the GLSurface as View to this Activity
    setContentView(glSurface);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Run.this, R.drawable.theygonelovemeformyambition);
                mPlayer.setLooping(true);
                mPlayer.start();
                while(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    android.os.SystemClock.sleep(100);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                String TAG = null;
                Log.d(TAG,"ERROR PLAYING");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }}).start();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    mPlayer.release();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi before you have to release media player resources. You should stop media player like below.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(mPlayer.isPlaying())
       mPlayer.stop();

    mPlayer.release();

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: That does NOT WORK! is there a different process for Opengl?

Comment: change the line 'MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Run.this, R.drawable.theygonelovemeformyambition);'
 to  'mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Run.this, R.drawable.theygonelovemeformyambition);'

Comment: When I press the back button it keeps saying "stopped unexpectedly" and the Music doesn't stop.

Comment: THAT WORKED ... YOUR THE GREATEST :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont have innitialized the mPlayer
In the  public void run()  you are just creating a new MediaPlayer
and so when you are trying mPlayer.release();   you are reffering to the null  mPlayer  and so you get a nullPointerExceptionerror (i guess)